# SQLAlchemy - TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE

Tags: sqlalchemy, py-postgresql

I am trying to save time represented as string from SQLAlchemy into a Postgresql table of which column is of type time without time zone.
I have defined SQLAlchemy column as Time(timezone=False).
The input values looks like the following: '09:23:00'.
When trying to save the data i always get sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (postgresql.exceptions.ParameterError) could not pack parameter $2::TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE for transfer.

Any hint/help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This error message is emitted when the engine is configured with the [py-postgresql](https://pypi.org/project/py-postgresql/) driver.  It can be avoided by passing the time as a datetime.time instance rather than as a string ([similar error report on GitHub](https://github.com/python-postgres/fe/issues/99)).

```py
import atexit
import datetime as dt

import sqlalchemy as sa

metadata = sa.MetaData()
tbl = sa.Table('t32560515', metadata, sa.Column('time', sa.Time(timezone=False)))

engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql+pypostgresql://souser:password@localhost:5432/test', echo=True)
atexit.register(engine.dispose)
metadata.drop_all(engine)
metadata.create_all(engine)

time_ = '09:23:00'
time_ = dt.time(*map(int, time_.split(':')))
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(tbl.insert().values(time=time_))
```

```
test# table t32560515 ;
   time   
══════════
 09:23:00
(1 row)
```

Use of the py-postgresql driver was [deprecated](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.pypostgresql) in SQLAlchemy 1.4. Support for the driver was removed in SQLAlchemy 2.0.